# Изменения при hover лишь для родительского элемента

Tags: css, css3

Каким образом можно сделать так, дабы при наведении при наведении на любой из li, жирным делался именно этот li, а не все сразу?

```css
 li:hover{
      font-weight: bold;
      cursor: pointer;
    }
```

```html
 <ul id="tree">
    <li>Животные
      <ul>
        <li>Млекопитающие
          <ul>
            <li>Коровы</li>
            <li>Ослы</li>
            <li>Собаки</li>
            <li>Тигры</li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li>Другие
          <ul>
            <li>Змеи</li>
            <li>Птицы</li>
            <li>Ящерицы</li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li>Рыбы
      <ul>
        <li>Аквариумные
          <ul>
            <li>Гуппи</li>
            <li>Скалярии</li>
          </ul>

        </li>
        <li>Морские
          <ul>
            <li>Морская форель</li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
```

Comment: Так верстку свою поменяйте, зачем вы в li вложили ul?

Comment: @МаксимВоробьев Что в этом такого? это вполне нормально.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если правильно понимаю, то при наведении, чтобы только родительский `li` подсвечивался, то можно так:

```css
li:hover>span {
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<ul id="tree">
  <li><span>Животные</span>
    <ul>
      <li><span>Млекопитающие</span>
        <ul>
          <li>Коровы</li>
          <li>Ослы</li>
          <li>Собаки</li>
          <li>Тигры</li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><span>Другие</span>
        <ul>
          <li>Змеи</li>
          <li>Птицы</li>
          <li>Ящерицы</li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li><span>Рыбы</span>
    <ul>
      <li><span>Аквариумные</span>
        <ul>
          <li>Гуппи</li>
          <li>Скалярии</li>
        </ul>

      </li>
      <li><span>Морские</span>
        <ul>
          <li>Морская форель</li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```